# appending a variable to a file in Bash not working

Tags: bash

I have a code like this

```
#! /bin/bash

$version = "1.0";
$preffix = "ApplicationName.";

for f in pack*;
do
    echo "bla bla bla" > myFile.txt
    echo $preffix >> myFile.txt
    echo "more stuff" >> myFile.txt
    echo $version >> myFile.txt
done;
```

the output is

```
bla bla bla

more stuff
```

$version and $preffix are not added to myFile.txt... why?

Comment: Surely you got a pair of `bash: =: command not found` errors? You really should pay attention to them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This program will work where yours doesn't:

```
#!/bin/bash

version="1.0";
preffix="ApplicationName.";

for f in pack*;
do
    echo "bla bla bla" > myFile.txt
    echo $preffix >> myFile.txt
    echo "more stuff" >> myFile.txt
    echo $version >> myFile.txt
done;
```

Your affection for spaces makes your program more readable, and also makes it not work.

Also, while it doesn't matter for this program, it would be a really good idea to do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

version="1.0";
preffix="ApplicationName.";

for f in pack*;
do
    echo "bla bla bla" > myFile.txt
    echo "$preffix" >> myFile.txt
    echo "more stuff" >> myFile.txt
    echo "$version" >> myFile.txt
done;
```

This is because if you did something like:

```
version='1  2'
```

in your original program, you would end up with a somewhat unexpected result. Putting the quotes around your variables is a really good idea to prevent mysterious errors like that.

Comment: Quoting the variables in this case will only keep any whitespace from being collapsed; bash only interprets variables once, so `a='$(ls -l)'; echo $a; echo "$a"` will print `$(ls -l)` twice, it doesn't go back and expand it again.

Comment: @Kevin: Oh, that's very interesting to know. Well, reduces the potential security issues of not quoting properly. I should've tested before I said something. I modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

The `$` sign in front of variables is used to read them.

If you want to assign them, you have to leave out the `$` sign, i.e.:

```
version="1.0"
preffix="ApplicationName."
```

Also, the `;` are not required at the end of the assignment lines.

Comment: thanks. I did the changes but the problem persists.

Comment: You should also remove space around =. Just like in above answer.

Comment: Also, just because it's good practice `echo "$preffix" >>myFile.txt` and `echo "$version" >>myFile.txt`.